# Connecting json page to and flex row in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, reactjs-flux

I have a problem about the flex row in react native so the thing is I need to use only one json data file to generate the list. However, I really cannot figure out how.

I just created 2 separate json but the problem is they just listing with delay one to another. And I want only one.

```
 export default class Detay extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        ApiTitle: [],
        ApiTitle2: []
            }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://oyleboyle.com/data.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ ApiTitle: response.data.aparatifler });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      axios.get('http://oyleboyle.com/data2.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ ApiTitle2: response.data.aparatifler });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    }


    renderItem(){

    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.flexview}>
        <View>{this.state.ApiTitle.map((id, i)=>
            <Urun title={id.title} image="https://nelazimsa.carrefoursa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/turk-kahvesi.jpg" fiyat="12"/>

           )}
          </View>

        <View>{this.state.ApiTitle2.map((id, i)=>

            <Urun title={id.title} image="https://nelazimsa.carrefoursa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/turk-kahvesi.jpg" fiyat="12"/>

        )}
          </View>

          </View>

          </ScrollView>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        flexview: {
        flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' , 
        marginTop: 10 , 
        justifyContent:'space-around'
        },
        img: {
          width: 280, 
          height: 280, 
          alignItems: 'center', 
          overflow: 'hidden'
        },
        titlee: {
          textAlign: 'center', 
          color: 'red', 
          fontSize: 18
        },
        fiyatt: {
          textAlign: 'center', 
          marginTop: 5
        },
        sepett: {
          color: 'white' ,
          textAlign: 'center', 
          marginTop: 5, 
          fontSize: 22 , 
          backgroundColor: 'red', 
          borderRadius: 7
        },
        kart: {
          borderRadius: 8, 
          padding: 5
        }
      });
```

I'm using row and I need two columns listing at the same with only 1 json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your two arrays to one by doing the following:

```
 //copy the old state of ApiTitle and add new items from response.data
 this.setState({ ApiTitle: [...this.state.ApiTitle, ...response.data.aparatifler]});
```

**Full Code:**

```
componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://oyleboyle.com/data.json')
      .then(response => {
        // here we are copying the content of ApiTitle and the content of repsonse.data together 
        this.setState({ ApiTitle: [...this.state.ApiTitle, ...response.data.aparatifler]});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      axios.get('http://oyleboyle.com/data2.json')
      .then(response => {
        // here we are copying the content of ApiTitle and the content of repsonse.data together again 
        this.setState({ ApiTitle: [...this.state.ApiTitle, ...response.data.aparatifler]});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

Your combined array can then be visualized with a FlatList.

```
renderItem(item, index) {
  // render your items in return 
  return (
    <View key={index} style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text> id: {item.id} </Text>
        <Text> titel: {item.title} </Text>
        <Text> fiyat: {item.fiyat} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
        data={this.state.ApiTitle}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**Demo Output:**

[image: demo]

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/Bk95rc_nE

Comment: hello, I edited the code and wrote more information about it. could you please check

Comment: @Jamiryo you don't want to merge the data? You just want to display them side by side?

Comment: It is already working but uses 2 separate data. I want to create only 1 file and use that data

Comment: @Jamiryo Look at my answer, the first code snippet shows how to merge it into one

Comment: Let me clear the whole thing :) the problem is flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' I want use only 1 data and list that data side by side without issue.

Comment: @Jamiryo i've updated my answer. You should still use FlatList, it is the recommended way to render a dynamic amount of data

Comment: you are lifesaver